# How can I prevent users from reading a variable in Java?

Tags: java, android, jakarta-mail

I'm programming an Android app in Java, and part of the app sends an email from my email account to another email account. I'm using JavaMail to achieve this.

It's all working very well, except my password for the email account that I'm sending from is hardcoded into a variable in my program. I don't want to user to be able to access this variable. Do I need to encrypt it? How would I go about doing that? Is there a way to configure JavaMail so I don't have to store my password anywhere on the device?

Here is the code that I'm using to store the email and password. It's just static variables in their own class:

```
public class Config {
      public static final String EMAIL ="[email]@gmail.com";
      public static final String PASSWORD ="[password]"; 
}
```

I've tried activating two-factor authentication on the account, but JavaMail fails in that case.

I don't want to go into the specifics of the app, but no one outside of my home city would have any reason to ever download this app. It's for an entirely local purpose. It's a password that I've never used anywhere else and it's an email account that I made specifically for this application, so I'm not taking a major risk here. I would still like to be as safe as possible.

Comment: Does it have to be an email? You could post to a google spreadsheet for example. Or if you have the resources have a dedicated web server.

Comment: It must be received by a certain email address. The method of execution does not matter, although a web server may not be possible in this situation. Is it possible to use a Google Form from the context of my Activity? I've researched it but I haven't found a way yet.

Comment: You can create a survey in Google Spreadsheet and post all the data there. Then you can go and see the responses, maybe you can even be notified by email each time someone posts something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you hard-code your password into the program there's no way to prevent someone from getting it out if they want to.

Instead of sending the email from the app, you could set up a web server that the app can connect to.  If sending the email is a must you can then send the email from this web server.  This way the credentials are on your private server rather than on the app you send to everyone.

Comment: This is probably the best option. Just use a simple hosted PHP script you can hit with all the credentials built in. Voila, protected.

Answer (score -1):

use private variables instead of public variables. please refer this [Java Access Modifiers](http://www.javatpoint.com/access-modifiers)

Comment: Access modifiers do not provide any security.  They are a tool for the developer only.  Do not assume data is safe just because it is in a private variable.